# Splitting by indices: I want to split the train + test from the data whose indices have been given. How shall I get train/test df?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

for example= df is the data with features. I want to split the train + test from the data whose indices have been given. How shall I get train/test df.

```
df=
0 2 0.3 0.5 0.5
1 4 0.5 0.7 0.4
2 2 0.5 0.1 0.4
3 4 0.4 0.1 0.3
4 2 0.3 0.1 0.5
```

where train.txt is

```
train=pd.read_csv(data_train.txt)
```

where in this dataframe indices are given. How should I get the training data from those indices?

Contents in data_train.txt(there are 10000 of data in which train indices are given in this txt file)

```
0
2
4
```

I want these indices for training data with feature:- like

final train should look like this (see the index):

```
0 2 0.3 0.5 0.5
2 2 0.5 0.1 0.4
4 2 0.3 0.1 0.5
```

Comment: Welcome to SO; lease spend a minute to see how to properly format code and text in your questions (done it for you, this time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a df as given by:

```
   0  1    2    3    4
0  0  2  0.3  0.5  0.5
1  1  4  0.5  0.7  0.4
2  2  2  0.5  0.1  0.4
3  3  4  0.4  0.1  0.3
4  4  2  0.3  0.1  0.5
```

and another train_indices as given by:

```
   0
0  0
1  2
2  4
```

then all you need to do to get the corresponding rows of `df` depends on how the data is organised:

```
#if you're trying to match the index of the df itself
train_df = df.iloc[train_indices]
#if you're trying to match column 0, which might be important 
#if it's not aligned to the index
train_df =  df.loc[df[0].isin(train_indices)]
```

Both of these (in this case) return:

```
   0  1    2    3    4
0  0  2  0.3  0.5  0.5
2  2  2  0.5  0.1  0.4
4  4  2  0.3  0.1  0.5
```

Comment: I mean I tried different way other around-
```
X, Y = sklearn.datasets.load_svmlight_file(Data_xt')
train_id = any txt read function('data-train-indices.txt')
trainX = X[train_id,:]
trainY = Y[train_id,:] -- it says it needs to be integer, what should be the solution?
```

Comment: I read the data-train-indices.txt as a pandas csv, which defaulted them to integers rather than strings. To get around this, call `indices = np.array(indices).astype(int)` (presuming your indices are called "indices".

Comment: Thanks, i'll try this! also the last thing you provided, why it has column 1? I guess it should not be there, can you please clarify? Column 1(2,2,2), I mean I just need my indices to extract the data, so the train has the features for all the indexed rows( 0,2,4,10,59....,103...10000)

Comment: That's because I read that df you gave as-is, meaning that I read that as a column. If it is not present in your dataframe then it will not be there after you index.

Comment: Ah, I see! Thanks, I will try and make a comment, if I have any issues. But please do reply:-)

Comment: Please approve the answer above if it works for you,  too!

Comment: Yeah, definitely:-), I will try it tomorrow!